# Liaison dans « et aussi »

Tags: liaisons

Pourquoi il n’y a pas de liaison dans « et aussi » ?

Comment se lit correctement cette phrase ?

Comment: Question similaire: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14863

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La liaison en français est soit obligatoire, soit interdite, soit optionnelle. Voir un tableau récapitulatif sur les liaisons obligatoires et les liaisons interdites, sur [le Point du FLE](http://www.lepointdufle.net/ressources_fle/liaisons_obligatoires_liaisons_interdites.htm#.VCektq1I5wg) (On en trouve de nombreux autres).
La liaison après le mot *et* fait partie des « liaisons interdites ».

Les liaisons étaient plus systématiques en ancien et moyen français qu'elles ne le sont aujourd'hui, surtout quand la présence de la consonne finale était étymologique. Certaines de ces liaisons ont disparu ou sont devenues facultatives, essentiellement parce que la prononciation de cette consonne finale ne s'est plus faite.

Mais bien que la présence du *t* dans la conjonction *et* soit étymologique (du latin *et*) ce *t* non seulement ne se prononçait déjà plus en gallo-romain mais il avait souvent quasi disparu de la graphie<sup>1</sup>. Le mot s'est écrit *e* pendant longtemps et le *t* a été réintroduit  au XII<sup>e</sup> siècle<sup>2</sup>. La prononciation est restée inchangée /e/.

<sub>1. On peut faire le rapprochement avec l'espagnol *y* (du même mot latin *et*) d'où le *t* a disparu aussi.</sub>
<sub>2. Il s'agit d'une « réfection graphique étymologique » (*Dictionnaire historique de la langue française*, sld Alain Rey).</sub>

Comment: Je me doutais bien que c'était l'explication historique, mais je n'ai pas pu trouver confirmation dans aucune de mes sources. +1 vote.

Answer (score 4):

**Il n'y a jamais liaison après *et*.** La phrase se prononce donc comme si la conjonction s'écrivait *é*.